# How to access (use) passwords stored in MySQL myLogin.cnf from batch and desktop applications

Tags: mysql, syntax, batch-processing, desktop-application, my.cnf

I need to reference the password stored in myLogin.cnf **from a batch script and a desktop application's connection string**. I've also added MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE as an environment variable, but the MySQL website mentions it once and only in the fact that it exists, and I can't find any viable documentation on it. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about it? The syntax to reference the password would be great. My scripts and application work fine with hardcoded passwords, but...

My Setup is: Windows 10 running MySQL 8.0 (No Install) Thank you

Comment: Yesterday you asked the same question and you said my comment pointed you in the correct direction and you solved the problem.

Comment: I misspoke. I did state that I had not yet applied your answer and that it pointed in the right direction. I was able to get to acknowledge me on the command line. However, you never answered my question regarding accessing the information from a batch script and desktop application. MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE does not appear to be an answer to that, and if it is, my syntax is off.

Comment: The syntax is just the pathname to the `.myLogin.cnf` file. On Linux it would be `export MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE=/path/to/file`. I don't know the equivalent syntax on Windows, but it seems like something an experienced Windows batch programmer should know.

Comment: Probably something like `SET %MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE% = C:\path\to\file`

Comment: When you said environment variable, where you talking about a system or user environment variable on Windows? Also, can you see what's wrong with the following statement? mysql -uroot --password=!newP! --execute="ALTER USER root IDENTIFIED BY '" --login-path=client "';".

Comment: You shouldn't be using `--password`. The whole point of `.myLogin.cnf` is that the `mysql` command reads it automatically.

Comment: I realize that, I'm only using --password as I'm testing, but I'm trying to get rid of it now

Comment: But what does that have to do with using the configuration file?

Comment: I actually trying to set the root password to the value that is stored in myLogin.cnf.

Comment: I don't think there's an API for reading the file.

Comment: Would you happen to know the syntax that I would use in a connection string from the desktop application?

Comment: You just leave out `--user` and `--password`, and it gets them from `.mylogin.cnf` automatically.

Comment: That doesn't work